# HTML Bootstrap - Timeline-like

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to HTML/CSS and Bootstrap but I'm building a simple website where I have three panels one below the other and they are separated by few pixels.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" id="panel5">
...
</div>
<connector_would_go_here>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" id="panel5">
...
</div>
```

I wanted to give the user the feeling that all these three panels are connected, similarly to a time-line. However differently than the time-line that creates a "spine" and links everything, I want them to be connected from the middle bottom to middle top. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Maybe You can prepare any draft (image etc.) how it should looks like?

Answer (score 0):

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w46p6zt2/1/

The connector could be any element, e.g. a div with a special class. Then try this style:

```
.connector {
    display: block;
    background: #DDD;
    width: 2px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin centers the element, and it is displayed as a 2x10 rectangle of color `#DDD`. Adjust however you like. Make sure to kill the margin on the panels, though.